# Django-Static files, how to close yourdoman/static file index

Tags: django

How to close Index of /Static/ from viewing them by the visitor of your website in django[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTfZi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/) for serving your static files. While using whitenoise, you can configure `Index Files` according to the documentations. [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#index-files)

Comment: Thank for replying me nima, i had modify my nginx file configuration so /static/ and /media/ take index.html inside static and media folder to stop the indexing inside my static and media images,